# Outbound messages issue

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I'm setting up a web service for a SF outbound messages. I have it working now, but noticed a problem:

message is POSTed to the specified url if it for some reason fails the repeated calls are GET request without any data. So they repeatedly fail with "Bad request" error.

Comment: What data does your outbound message include? When implementing a web service in .NET to receive the outbound messages I've never had an issue with the data not coming through on reties. Are you sending back a ACK on success and a NACK on failure?

Comment: Are the retries POST or GET?

Comment: I'd expect them to all be consistent. A HTTP POST makes the most sense to transfer the SOAP message to the web service. Where have you implemented the receiving service? If you aren't sending back a clean NACK on failure something odd might be occurring.